# Modulo operation for integers and reals?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I read that the modulo operation finds remainder after division.
My misconseption here is about the remainder.
Is the remainder the last digit of the result? I thought it was the first.

Example: $5/7 = 0.7142857142857142857...$

$5 \mod 8 = 7$.

$7/3 = 2.33333..$ but $7 \mod 3 = 1$. Remainder of the first result is point 3333...

$9/4 = 2.25$ $9 \mod 4 = 1$. Ok same as first but different remainder.

$9/7 = 1.2857142857142...$ $9 \mod 7 = 2$. What? Remainder is two, the first digit. This is probably "random" for reals? But not for integers?

$111111111$ : If there are nine ones we should divide by $7$, it gives $2$ remnants. Since $9-2=7$ ones.
So using modulo operation on the reals is not something one should do?

Comment: "Is the remainder the last digit of the result? I thought it was the first."

Neither. The remainder of dividing $a$ by $b$ is the unique integer $r$ such that there exists an integer $q$ such that $a = bq+r$ and $0 \leq r < b$. It has absolutely nothing to do with decimal expansions at all. You can define an equivalent operation on the reals: just replace "unique integer $r$" above with "unique real number $r$".

Comment: It is remainder of the *Euclidean* division (between integers, no decimal part).

Comment: "This is probably "random" for reals? But not for integers?"  What are you talking about. 9,7, and 2 are all integers.  "111111111 :...So using modulo operation on the reals is not something one should do?"  What are you talking about? 111111111 is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to compute $a \bmod b$ with $a,b$ positive integers, you do division like you learned in school and write $a=qb+r$ where $q$ is the quotient and $r$ is the remainder.  We typically choose $r$ to be in the range $0$ to $b-1$.  Then we write $r=a \bmod b$, so is you want $1234 \bmod 7$, you write $1234=176\cdot 7 + 2$, so $1234 \bmod 7=2$.  You don't need to do anything with the decimal expansion.

The main time I have seen the modulo operation used with the modulus $b$ other than an integer is reducing angles of a circle when the angles are measured in radians.  You compute an angle, then take it $\mod 2\pi$ to put the angle in the range $[0,2\pi)$.  You can use other moduli, but this is the common one.

Comment: Never heard of “modulo $2\pi$”?

Comment: @egreg:  Yes, but I didn't think of it.  I will incorporate

Comment: @egreg: Given any distinct points $A,B,C,D$ on a circle, $∠ABD = ∠ACD$ mod $180°$, where the angles are directed. Without directed angles and modulo arithmetic, many theorems in euclidean geometry will have cases proliferating like bunnies in any truly rigorous proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine a couple of your examples.

First $\dfrac{7}3 = \color{#0a0}2.333\ldots = \color{#0a0}2 + \dfrac{\color{#c00}1}3\ $ has quotient $\color{#0a0}2$ and remainder $\color{#c00}1$

without fractions: $\ 7 = \color{#0a0}2\cdot 3 + \color{#c00}1$

and $\,\ \dfrac{9}7 = \color{#0a0}1.286\ldots = \color{#0a0}1 + \dfrac{\color{#c00}2}7\ $ has quotient $\color{#0a0}1$ and remainder $\color{#c00}2$

without fractions: $\ 9 = \color{#0a0}1\cdot 7 + \color{#c00}2$

Generally we  have $\, a = \color{#0a0}q\cdot b + \color{#c00}r\ $ with remainder $\ \color{#c00}r = a\bmod b\,$ obeying $\, 0\le r < b$

which is obtained by (long) dividing $a$ by $b\,$ (Euclidean division with remainder)

This remainder $r$ is the *least* natural of the form $\, a-q\,b\,$ for some integer $q$.

Said procedurally: continually add/subtract $b$ from $a$ till you land in the interval $[0,b)$

Note that if $a, b\neq 0$ are reals then the prior procedure still works fine.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac 73 = 2\frac 13 = 2.333333....$ but neither $\frac 13$ nor $0.33333....$ are the "remainder".  $\frac 13$ and $0.3333....$ are the *values* of the result of dividing a value by a divisor that is larger than it.

The "remainder" is what *remains* after you have divided everything that will fit in in evenly.  $2*3 = 6 < 7$ and $3*3 = 9 > 7$.  So the most we can evenly fit $3$ into $7$ is $2$ times.  That leaves $7- 2*3 = 1$ that we haven't dealt with and can't deal with unless we get a hammer.  So that is the *remainder*.

We can then take the remainder and a a big hammer and *pound* it into a fractional bit of $\frac 13$ or $0.33333....$ and take care of it that way.   But then ... we have dealt with it.  And *nothing* remains.  Because we took care of it.

So by definition, the remainder is the *integer* that is left after we divide things evenly *before* we take the hammer and meat grinder to get the fractional parts.

Anyway... the actual digits of the decimal representations have nothing to do with anything.

...

To your examples:

> 5/7=0.7142857142857142857...

Um... you never do anything with it:

$5 = 0\times 7 + 5; 0*7 < 5 < 1*7$ so $5\div 7 = 0$ with $5$ remainder.  $\frac 57 = 0\frac 57$.  The remainder is $5$.

$5\equiv 5 \pmod 7$.

> 5mod8=7

That is incorrect.

$5 = 0\times 8 + 5; 0*8 < 5 < 1*8$ so $5\div 8 = 0$ with $5$ remainder.  $\frac 58 = 0\frac 58$.  The remainder is $5$.

$5\equiv 5 \pmod 8$.

> 7/3=2.33333.. but 7mod3=1. Remainder of the first result is point 3333...

$7 = 2\times 3 + 1; 2*3 < 7 < 3*3$ so $7\div 3 = 2$ with $1$ remainder.  $\frac 73 = 2\frac 13$.  The remainder is $1$.

$7\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

> 9/4=2.25 9mod4=1. Ok same as first but different remainder.

$9 = 2\times 4 + 1; 2*4 < 9 < 3*4$ so $9\div 4 = 2$ with $1$ remainder.  $\frac 94 = 2\frac 14$.  The remainder is $1$.

$9\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

> 9/7=1.2857142857142... 9mod7=2. What? Remainder is two, the first digit. This is probably "random" for reals? But not for integers?

$9 = 1\times 7 + 2; 1*7 < 9 < 2*7$ so $9\div 7 = 1$ with $2$ remainder.  $\frac 97 = 1\frac 27$.  The remainder is $2$.

$9\equiv 2 \pmod 7$.

The fact that the first digit of $\frac 27$ is $2$ is an irrelevent coincidence.

Decimals are not important.  There are days where I fantasize that it should be illegal to teach decimals outside of engineering and accounting classes.  Any way decimal expansion has *NOTHING* to do with this question.

> 111111111 : If there are nine ones we should divide by 7, it gives 2 remnants. Since 9−2=7 ones. So using modulo operation on the reals is not something one should do?

That is .... incomprehensible.

$1111111111 = 15873015\times 7 + 6;15873015*7 < 111111111 < 15873016*7$ so $111111111\div 7 = 15873015$ with $6$ remainder.  $\frac {111111111}7 = 15873015 \frac 67$.  The remainder is $6$.

$111111111\equiv 6 \pmod 7$.